# How to give footer background color for the whole width of the browser with fixed parent div

Tags: css

I am working on Bootstrap theme where its responsive. I disable the responsiveness on a child theme by adding a code in functions.php. All works well , no problem.

Now the parent container, is now fixed:
HTML:

```
 <div class="container">
```

CSS:

```
 .container{width: 940px;}
```

But I would like the footer section to have sitewide background color. How do I able to do this?

I have tried setting different methods like width:auto, width: 200% ,but its not giving me the desired result.

Supposing this is the footer section:

```
<footer>
   My footer
</footer>
```

My attempted CSS on a child theme(not working)

```
footer {
  background: #CCCCCC;
  width:100% !important;
  position:absolute !important;   

}
```

Also is this possible without setting too many !important on CSS property? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your footer is inside the `div.container` which has `width:940px;` then giving your footer 100% width will make it 940px wide.

You need to have the footer outside the container to give it 100% width of the body.

Answer (score 0):

When you give 100% width, the element gets its container's width. So in your code, even with the important keyword, it'll get the container's width (because that what 100% is supposed to do).

Just take the footer outside of the container.
Then it'll work and you won't need this !important keyword.

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, removing the `footer` from the parent container of `.container` will allow the width of it to be the entire size of the viewport/document.

If you are unable to change this level of structure of the HTML due to your template, you can fake the width using pseudo-elements, like so:

```
footer {
    position: relative;
    background-color: lightblue; /* Match the color of the body background */
}
footer::before, footer::after {
    content:"";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 9999px;
    /* some huge width */
    background-color: inherit;
}
footer::before {
    right: 100%;
}
footer::after {
    left: 100%;
}
```

See [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7zs77/).

Taken from [CSS Tricks: Full Browser Width Bars](http://css-tricks.com/full-browser-width-bars/)